# How can I run only a portion of a command line in a user built shell?

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line

I make a shell that takes arguments in a command line with special conditions on what it is able to do.

For example, anything that appears after the `#` character will be considered as a comment and the rest of the command line is rendered negligible.

Such as in the command `ls -lR /`, you would execute the program `/bin/ls` (performed using `execvp`) passing into it the parameters `-lR` and `/`.

But in the command `ls # -lR /`, only `/bin/ls` will run.

I have already made the parsing function that will tokenize command line into strings of separate arguments so I figured it would start from there.

However, I'm not sure how I would go about commenting out everything else after the `#` character in the CLI. I am using C++.

Comment: Read a lot more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques, e.g. [the Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_(computer_science))

Answer (score 1):

Only send parts of the line that occur before the ‘#’ to your tokenenize.

Comment: So how do i do that? Do I have to modify the tokenize function? I'm using strtok() for C++

Comment: First call strtok using “#” as your token, take only the first item returned from that, and now call strtok again, using your whitespace token.